# All files are not getting downloaded by SFTP script

Tags: shell-script, sftp, vsftpd, vsftp

I have a sftp file script with below details,my server folder like `BCP11,BCP12,BCP13,BCP14.....BCPXX`. In which `BCPDUMP` folder have files.

Filename :  `file_sftp.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn sftp user@xx.xxx.x.xxx
expect "user@xx.xxx.x.xxx's password:"
send "password\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "get *Backup/GetBackup/BCP*/*BCPDUMP/20150925/20150925_profile*\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\n"
```

When i am executing this script i am getting only one file while the server have approx 12 files. i am getting below script output.

```
spawn sftp user@xx.xxx.x.xxx  
Connecting to xx.xxx.x.xxx...  
Password:  
sftp> get *Backup/GetBackup/BCP*/*BCPDUMP/20150925/20150925_profile*  
Couldn't get handle: No such file or directory^M  
Couldn't get handle: No such file or directory^M  
Couldn't get handle: No such file or directory^M  
Fetching   /rsi/Backup/GetBackup/BCP10/BCPDUMP/20150925/20150925_profile_410.list.Z to 20150925_profile_410.list.Z
^M/rsi/Backup/GetBackup/BCP10/BCPDUMP/20150925/20150925_profile_410.list.Z 0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA^M/rsi/Backup/GetBackup/BCP10/BCPDUMP/20150925/20150925_profile_410.list.Z                                                           66% 1152KB   1.1MB/s   00:00 ETA^M/rsi/Backup/GetBackup/BCP10/BCPDUMP/20150925/20150925_profile_410.list.Z                                                          100% 1730KB 864.9KB/s   00:02
```

Comment: or use `scp` or `rsync`

Comment: I ran my script by below command and found my sftp session is closing by 20 secs. and in the mean time sftp downloading the file how much it can download with in 20 sec. please suggest how i can increase sftp session time. -bash-4.1$ date;./file_sftp.sh ;date

Comment: Are the files all called `20150925_profile_410.list.Z` and located in different directories? Or do they all have distinct names? If you download two files with the same name, the second one will overwrite the first. What does `ls *Backup/GetBackup/BCP*/*BCPDUMP/20150925/20150925_profile*` list?

Comment: All the files have different name.the naming convention is following. 20150925_profile_<XYZ>.list.Z. where XYZ is varying in the filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this construct when `command` is time consuming:

```
send "command\r"
expect { 
    timeout { 
        puts "Running..." 
        exp_continue 
    } 
    "%PROMPT%" { 
        puts "Finished." 
    } 
}
send "next command\r"
```

On `timeout` you will be continuosly waiting with `exp_continue` command for `%PROMPT%`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to retrieve directories you should use `get -r`. Try with that.

Comment: Try and add a little more explanation.

Comment: I ran my script by below command and found my sftp session is closing by 20 secs. and in the mean time sftp downloading the file how much it can download with in 20 sec. please suggest how i can increase sftp session time. -bash-4.1$ date;./file_sftp.sh ;date

Comment: Try running `sftp -vvv` so that you get the output of the communication and see what is going on. Try adding `ServerAliveInterval 120` to your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and see if it works. The server could have set that parameter though, so if the server is yours check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` mind the D in sshD_config.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this character for all ( * ) just once per line if you already know the names of the directories BCP* and *BCPDUMP.

If you think that it is not good idea typing the directories names in different lines you can use the `ls` command for listing all directories and get them into an array, after that you will download all available files for every array value which is different directory or different path.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you are using expect.

Use this code segment in your shell script ...

```
 ftp -i -n ftp.somehost.com  <<-EOF
   user somelogin somepassword
   mget *
   bye
   EOF
```

Note that each of the lines (user, mget, bye, EOF) start with a "tab" character.

Also note that if you are getting a specific set of files (provided it is greater than two files)

```
 mget file1 file2 file3 file4 ... filen
```

Comment: Hi Don W, FTP is not a secure protocol for file transferring in production server environment. That's why i am using sftp protocol.for doing sftp,i required expect.